# How to run async tasks in several threads in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I want to run some async tasks in several threads. I tried to use tokio's Runtime and `new_multi_thread`, but I've got a panic

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Cannot drop a runtime in a context where blocking is not allowed. This happens when a runtime is dropped from within an asynchronous context.'
```

Here's the code.

```rust
async fn routine(millis: u64) {
    tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(millis)).await;
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let rt = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread().worker_threads(2).enable_all().build().unwrap();

    let handles: Vec<tokio::task::JoinHandle<_>> = (1..10_u64).map(|i| {
        rt.spawn(routine(i))
    }).collect();

    for handle in handles {
        handle.await.unwrap();
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to initialize a runtime as that's what the annotation `#[tokio::main]` does (it's a macro).

This...

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    println!("hello");
}
```

...de-sugars to:

```rust
fn main() {
    tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread()
        .enable_all()
        .build()
        .unwrap()
        .block_on(async {
            println!("hello");
        })
}
```

Note that `#[tokio::main]` is equivalent to `#[tokio::main(flavor = "multi_thread")]` (defaults to multi-threaded runtime), as opposed to the single-threaded runtime `#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]`. In your case  you can use this form `#[tokio::main(worker_threads = 2)]`.

Comment: To have the multi-thread scheduler be used by default, the `rt-multi-thread` feature flag must be set
(https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/index.html#multi-thread-scheduler)

Answer (score 2):

`#[tokio::main]` creates a `Runtime` and runs `async fn main()` on it. Your `main` then creates another `Runtime`. Normally, when we create our own runtime, we wouldn't use the `#[tokio::main]` macro, we'd just write a normal `main`.

We can use `block_on` to wait for the tasks to complete, then we can drop the `Runtime`. With a normal `main`, we're not dropping the `Runtime` in an asynchronous context, so the program no longer panics.

```
async fn routine(millis: u64) {
    println!("in routine({millis})");
    tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(millis)).await;
}

fn main() {
    let rt = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread().worker_threads(2).enable_all().build().unwrap();

    let handles: Vec<tokio::task::JoinHandle<_>> = (1..10_u64).map(|i| {
        rt.spawn(routine(i))
    }).collect();

    rt.block_on(async {
        for handle in handles {
            handle.await.unwrap();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is building `tokio::runtime::Builder` same as `#[tokio::main(flavor="multi_thread", max_workers=100)] ` the same thing?

Comment: @collinsmarra You can use [`cargo expand`](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand) to see what macros like `#[tokio::main]` expand to. The [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) also has this feature under **Tools** > **Expand macros**, however the playground doesn't have all crates available (but it *does* have `tokio`).